# How to expose events in typescript so handlers can be defined by ES5 code?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-5

I have a TypeScript class that represents a textbox. I want to capture an event when text is changed and the typed text is a bad word and allow other code including ES5 code to handle it.

```
export class ParentalTextBox {
  private txt : HTMLInputElement;

 Attach(textbox : HTMLInputElement) {
    this.txt = textbox;
    this.txt.onchange = () => CheckForBadWords());
 }

 CheckForBadWords() {
  if (this.txt.value == "rascal") {
     // I want to fire an event for any handler to know that a bad word was
     // detected, here.
     //
   }
 }
}
```

I tried doing something like.

```
 OnBadWordDetected : (word : string, target : HTMLInputElement);
```

but this is giving me an error, I don't want to define it because I want ability for other ES5 users of my class to be able to assign a handler like so

```
var myobj = new TypeScriptModule.ParentalTextBox();
myobj.Attach(document.getElementById("searchbox"));

myobj.OnBadWordDetected = function(word, target) {
 alert("I will tell your parents now!");
}
```

How do I achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

If its a function, you need to define the return type as well:

```
OnBadWordDetected : (word : string, target : HTMLInputElement) => any;
```

If you don't care what the return type is, `any` will allow functions with any return type.